# Python adding a 'Â' symbol infront of the 'µ' symbol when trying to parse an XML file

Tags: python, encoding, beautifulsoup

The intended encoding of the XML file is UTF-8.

I am reading in an XML file like this:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

infile = open(file,"r")
xml_file = infile.read()

xml_soup = BeautifulSoup(xml_file.encode('utf-8'),'lxml-xml')
```

Then I send it using a post request like so:

```
req = requests.Request('POST', 'url to post to',

               data=str(xml_soup).encode('utf-8'))

prepped_requ = req.prepare()
s = requests.Session()
http_response = s.send(prepped_requ)
print(http_response)
```

It reaches the endpoint, but in the process, it inexplicably inserts random 'Â' symbols infront of special symbols! Any idea what's going wrong? How exactly am I butchering my file?

Comment: Yes that's through, but there's a bit that I need to read it in, check for a certain thing, and then adjust it accordingly (if needed).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was this bit I was missing, the `encoding="utf-8"` bit while opening the file!

```
infile = open(file,"r",encoding="utf-8")
```